# html divs into php array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have this html code:

```
<div class="moviefilm">
SURSA 1
</div>

<div class="moviefilm">
SURSA 2
</div>

<div class="moviefilm">
SURSA 3
</div>
```

I want a php script to extract content of each  and push him to php array to use with function

```
foreach ($divs as $div) {
//PHP CODE
}
```

Comment: You'll want a DOM Parser, such as: https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser

Comment: For this basic example the built in DOMDocument class will do http://php.net/DOMDocument

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with javascript `getElementsByClassName` then pass it to php by AJAX or something